# How to lock writing file so other consumer can't consume

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am working on replacing data  in file (it's big file of 400 MB) using camel
and I am facing issue where other consumer pickup file even though file is in use (it's in writing mode).

Is there a way in Camel to lock file which is in writing mode so another consumer/route can't consume. It should consume once the writing is done. 
I tried with readLocks but no luck so far.

```
from("file://A").split().tokenize("\n", 999).streaming()
.log("Spliting::::::::::").unmarshal(csv).bean("transferDate", "enrich")
.marshal(csv).to("file://B?fileExist=Append");

from("file://B?delete=true").to("file://A"); // this route pick up file even the first route haven't finished writing file completely
```

Comment: do you have a specific business case you need fileExist=Append in your first route and deleting it in the second route. I would suggest in first route fileExist=Override and use tempFileName=tmpFile_${file:name} so that a temp file is being written to. Or you can use use doneFileName option in first route and in the second route pick the file when the doneFileName exists.

Comment: @Neeraj : I need fileExist=Append due to I am writing data in chucks of 999 and I am doing this because it's a very big file. I tried with tempFileName but it didn't work as Camel won't allow ( fileExist and tempFileName) to use both option at a time

Comment: This question's requirement is pretty close to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49762430/3759505)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure the Camel route with appropriate options for file reading and writing. In particular, you need to set the **readLock** and **readLockTimeout** options for the file endpoint.

```
 from("file:/input-directory")
        .routeId("fileRoute")
        .to("file:/output-directory?readLock=changed&readLockTimeout=5000")
        .log("File processed: ${file:name}")
        .end();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **done files**. If you configure them on the file consumer, it ignores all files until there is a done (or marker) file beside the real file.

You can also configure the file producer to create the done files.

See the [Camel Docs for File component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/file-component.adoc) and go done to the chapter `Using done files`.